# What is the minimum safe distance a human finger can be placed away from a live contact of 16A, 250V?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, electric-circuits, electric-fields, electric-current

what is the minimum safe distance a human finger can be placed away from a live contact of 16A, 250V and not get shock. Would this distance change if the air was humid? 
Would this distance change if it was a metal plate instead of human finger?
How would this distance change if it was through insulation and not through air?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How steady is your hand? But seriously, this question is entirely wrong-headed if you are concerned about safety. If anything is going to get close to an electrical contact, it must be de-powered. No exceptions!

Comment: The answer, is just a little more than your tailor recommends for your sleevelength.   Electricians always take precautions when working on live circuits, because it is generally not safe.

Answer (score 2):

First off, I will begin with the disclaimer: Power electronics is dangerous, and I would not consider any distance as you describe "safe."

The NFPA releases guidelines for such values.  There are actually [three major lines](http://arcadvisor.com/faq/shock-protection-approach-boundaries) which the NFPA chooses to draw:

- Limited Approach Boundary - This is a distance which an unqualified person should not cross (except with a qualified escort).  This is typically a larger value measured in feet, and notionally it is assumed to be 4 feet for <600V devices (plus some other criteria).  One may use a calculator to get closer
- Restricted Approach Boundary - This is a distance which a qualified person should not cross unless they have taken the time to put on the proper protective gear
- Prohibited Approach Boundary - Any close than this and a qualified individual must treat this situation as though they were making direct contact with the live circuit.

Obviously, given how many lines are drawn, you can see why you should not consider the distance you refer to as "safe."  It would be possible to [calculate](http://arcadvisor.com/faq/ieee-1584-calculation-procedure) the Prohibited Approach Boundary, which would be the closest to a "minimum safe distance" that could be recognized.

All that being said, there are some physics numbers you can use.  Dry air has a breakdown voltage of 3kV/mm.  That means that if the circuit calls for closing 2mm of dry air, you need 6kV of voltage to do that.  Once the air has broken down (known as an arc flash), it stops acting as an insulator and lets almost all of the current through.  This does indeed vary by humidity and gets quite a lot lower in damp air.  My advice would be to never get into a situation where I was dependent on dry-air calculations for my own safety.  Materials other than air have different breakdown voltages (oil cooled transformers use an oil that breaks down at 20kV/mm).  **One rule of thumb I would definitely rely on: if you have to ask Stack Exchange how high voltage electricity works, you should not be trying to explore the minimum safe distances to live contacts.**

I would not rely on these numbers for safety, but they can be used for some calculations, and it is nice to know what the actual physics looks like.  If you were making a Tesla Coil and needed to figure out how far such a voltage would arc in a non-safety-critical setting, you could use those sorts of values.  In reality, you should always leave a safe comfort zone around such circuits because you don't want your hand to brush against the contact by accident.  **You only get one heart, so try not to zap it with 250V circuits if you can help it!**  National groups such as the NFPA exist to help people not make mistakes with such high voltages, and I recommend following their advice (or whomever the local national group is where you live).

Comment: "if you have to ask Stack Exchange how high voltage electricity works, you should not be trying to explore the minimum safe distances to live contacts"   I second that.

Answer (score 0):

CAVEAT: Stay safe. Don't work with open voltage sources unless you have been properly trained to do so. 250V can kill you ! Even if it doesn't, it's really quite painful. Trust me, it really hurts a lot.

But 250V is not going to arc either, so you won't get any shock unless you actually touch or are in extreme physical proximity (i.e. less than 1mm). If you are in proximity of a life wire, you are already doing it wrong and you shouldn't be counting mm you should move away.

The Paschen curves https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paschen's_law do describe arc distance for different gases and voltages, but 250V in air is close to 0. For consumer electronics product you need to keep primary PCB traces (connected to power outlet) and secondary PCB traces (could be touched by a human) about 6mm apart and that accounts also for creepage over time.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful if you are talking about AC or DC voltage.  DC is even more dangerous and can arc a few millimeters.